# how can I rebuild the dropdownButton instantly , when I delete the items from DropdownMenuItem

Tags: flutter, contextmenu, dropdownbutton

I have a dropdownButton , where I add few things to list , then using contextMenu with edit and delete I manipulate the list , I want the manipulated list to be displayed instantly when I remove the item . as  of now If I reopen the dropdown  I am able to see updated items.
[image]

I tried using global keys and also Unique Key . using Unique key closed dropdown . I dont want to close and reopen the dropdown again to get the updated list.

```
class _ChatDropdownState extends State<ChatDropdown> { List<Profile> dropdownProfiles = []; 
late DropdownProvider _dropdownProvider;
@override void initState() { super.initState(); dropdownProvider = context.read<DropdownProvider>(); WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(() { _loadDropdownData(); }); }
Future<void> _loadDropdownData() async { dropdownProfiles = Preferences.instance.getProfiles(); String? selectedProfile = Preferences.instance.getSelectedProfile(); setState(() { _dropdownProvider.setDropdownItems(dropdownProfiles); if (_dropdownProvider.selectedValue == null && selectedProfile != null) { _dropdownProvider.setSelectedValue(selectedProfile); } }); }
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { String? selectedValue = context .select<DropdownProvider, String?>((value) => value.selectedValue);
List<Profile> dropdownItems =
    context.select<DropdownProvider, List<Profile>>(
        (value) => value.dropdownItems);

return Column(
  children: [
    DropdownButton<String>(
      value: selectedValue,
      key: UniqueKey(),
      items: [
        const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'addProfile',
          child: Text('Add Profile'),
        ),
        ...dropdownItems.reversed.map((profile) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: profile.title,
            child: GestureDetectorWithContextMenu(
              onTap: () => {
                onTapDefaults(),
              },
              contextMenuBuilder: (_, primaryAnchor) =>
                  _DropDownSelectionToolbar(
                      primaryAnchor: primaryAnchor,
                      title: profile.title,
                      context: profile.context,
                      character: profile.character),
              child: Text(profile.title),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ],
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        if (value == 'addProfile') {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return const EditChatDialog();
            },
          );
        } else {
          _dropdownProvider.setSelectedValue(value);
          Preferences.instance.setSelectedProfile(value!);
        }
      },
    ),
  ],
);
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

To rebuild the `DropdownButton` instantly when you delete items from `DropdownMenuItem`, you can use the `setState` method to trigger a rebuild of the widget tree whenever you modify the list of dropdown items. Since you're already using `setState` to update the dropdown items, you need to ensure that modifications to the dropdown items list are reflected in the UI

Comment: yeah right now  I am using UniqueKey so that  once I delete the item dropdowncloses and when I reopen the item is deleted . can you elaborate on how to ensure the modifications  to rebuild without closing dropdown .